# How to schedule jobs to run at different times for different users

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a feature that allows the user to schedule a report to be generated by the server.

i.e. User A wants to schedule the report to be generated and emailed to him at 5 PM every day 
whereas User B wants to schedule the same at 10 AM every day.

There can be many users wanting the job to run at any time of their choosing.

I see there is something called node-schedule: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

where you can do this:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule'); 

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){ 
    console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!'); 
});
```

to execute a cron job when the minute is 42 of each hour.

Something like this might work if the system only has one user, but for multiple users, I can't hardcode the time to schedule the job. Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule'); 

let schedules = {};
schedules[`${userId1}`] = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * 1 *', function(){ 
    console.log('Generating report for user 1!'); 
}); 
schedules[`${userId2}`] = schedule.scheduleJob('42 3 * * *', function(){ 
    console.log('Generating report for user 2!'); 
}); 
schedules[`${userId3}`] = schedule.scheduleJob('42 2 * * *', function(){ 
    console.log('Generating report for user 3!'); 
});
```

userId1 Execute a cron job when the minute is 42(every hours) and month is Jan

userId2 Execute a cron job when the minute is 42(every day) and hour is 3 am

userId3 Execute a cron job when the minute is 42(every day) and hour is 2 am

Comment: This did not quite answer my question. What to do if User 2 wants the job scheduled at a different TIME from User 1? Your answer suggest that all users schedule the job at the same time.

Comment: No. `'42 * * 1 *'`, `'42 3 * * *'`, `'42 2 * * *'` Is not the same time.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Is this solution scalable though? If there were 1 million users, that would mean 1 milliion jobs are scheduled and held in memory?

Comment: Yes, this suppose storage in memory. I never checked how scalable is it. But you always can do it and share your experience :-)

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to scale well and is heavily redundant.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide a more scalable and less redundant solution to help others?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem ,then suddenly this method clicked in my mind.
You can use For loop for this purpose and this will schedule job for each user at the required time.

```
user.forEach(async(usersData) => {
    schedule.scheduleJob(usersData.date, async() => {
        const sendEmail = await mailService.sendMail(usersData.email, subject, usersData.email);
        if (sendEmail) {
        console.log("Email Sended");
            
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: This is somewhat ok when you have a fixed user base. What if your user base is changing? Some users are added and some removed?

Comment: Yes you are right.